# Confused about which variables should be dependent and independent in this MANOVA

Tags: manova

I am currently doing research on social media and how it can effect depression, anxiety and stress scale (DASS) scores. I have two age groups (18-25, 26-35) and also took scores on narcissistic personality inventory (NPI). I'm struggling to know what statistical test to do. I was thinking MANOVA with age as my independent variable and time spent on social networks, NPI scores and DASS scores as my three dependent variables. Is this correct?

My research question is: Does social network use affect DASS scores and NPI scores in two age groups?

Comment: I have no idea. What is the theoretical question you are trying to answer?

Comment: Does social network use affect DASS scores and NPI scores in two age groups

Answer (score 3):

Based on your theoretical question, it sounds like you think of DASS and NPI as your dependent variables, time spend on social networks as your independent variable, and age as a covariate.  So I would use a MANOVA (or MANCOVA) with only DASS and NPI as your DVs.